# React + Redux + axios, обновление данных

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Добрый день я новичок в ReactJS, подскажите как правильно обновить данные которые отправляются post запросом (парсинг новых данных).

Comment: В поисковиках же вагон информации https://codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-3-with-reactjs-and-angular/video/react-create-post

Comment: А именно через axios?

Comment: новый гет запрос за новыми данными или в ответе пост запроса присылать новые данные, какие еще могут варианты?

Comment: а как новые данные передать через пост запрос в get? У меня данные получается передать, но они получаются не Ajax запросом, компонент не рендерит новый get запрос, только после рефреша страницы рендерит.